# Image resize in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-resizing

Like this I am currently uploading a file ( image ) in my ruby application .. I need to resize the image after uploading ... please help for resizing the image

uploaded_io = params[:category][:thumb]

```
if uploaded_io != ""
  name = uploaded_io.original_filename
  if(FileTest.exist?("#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/data/#{name}"))
    id = Category.maximum('id').to_s
    id = id.to_i+ 1
    name =id.to_s+"_"+name
  end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have imagemagick already installed - then use ImageScience or MiniMagick instead, they both use much less resources and work faster, and are installed just as a common gem (actually a little bit more installation for imagescience)

ImageScience:

```
ImageScience.with_image("#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/data/#{name}") do |image|
  image.thumbnail(100) do |thumb|
    thumb.save <path_to_small_image to be saved>
  end     
end
```

MiniMagick:

```
MiniMagick::Image.new("#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/data/#{name}").resize "100x100"
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply and ... with out Magick is there is any other ruby native ( some thing like in php ) method for resizing image ? I am asking this because some problems with installing GEM in my system 

Thanks

Comment: hmmmm do you have ImageMagick installed? it's not a ruby gem, and if yes - then you can call its commands without any gems

Comment: Not ImageMagick installed in my system .... Some problem while I tried to install . If you don't mind please help me how to install the same on my system ?

Comment: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php or if you are using ubuntu - then just `sudo apt-get update`  
`sudo apt-get install imagemagick --fix-missing` should do the trick

Comment: I see, you're using Win 7. Never done that for windows, but i think binary release is what you're looking for

Comment: oh yes .. I am using windows 7 .. any idea for installing that ?

Answer (score 1):

Try RMagick!

```
require 'RMagick'

img = Image.new name
thumb = img.scale(125, 125)
thumb.write "thumb.gif"
```

http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/comtasks.html#thumb

Comment: hi .. can you please help to how to install RMagick in my server .. I am using windows 7

Thanks