# How to change Rails app for Paperclip + ImageMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, image-resizing

I want to resize an image on the fly in Rails application. Everybody suggests using **Paperclip** gem.

The problem is: I ALREADY HAVE column with pictures:

```
add_column :users, :picture, :binary, :null => true
```

and the application already has the code to upload this image. PostgreSQL database already has a column of "bytea" type.

**May I not change the database structure** and only do some changes to controller's method?:

```
def current_user_image
  if current_user.picture
    send_data current_user.picture #Do something here using Paperclip
  else
    send_file File.join(Rails.root, 'public', 'images', 'no_user_pic.png')
  end
end
```

**Related topics:**

- [Image resize in ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520062/image-resize-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Probably you can look at Imagemagick library to resize the image.

Comment: Is there some "pure gem" solution without having to install some system-wide libraries? May be as a plugin which could be dropped to Rails application's folders?

Comment: Rmagick can help you in your quest. but u still need imagemagick library under the hood to do image manipulation even with paperclip its the same story as it resize the image using imagemagick , If you want command to rezise an image in Rmagick here code that help you https://gist.github.com/2915286